# Stable webcomponent-like templating engine with data binding?

Tags: javascript, polymer, reactjs, template-engine, web-component

I'm looking for good frontend "template engine" of some sort. I've spent 2 days researching. I've looked into [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) (by Google), [Reactjs](http://facebook.github.io/react/) (by Facebook), [Skatejs](https://github.com/skatejs/skatejs#skate) (by Atlassian), [Rivet](http://rivetsjs.com/) (used by Dell) and [Angularjs directives](https://angularjs.org/) (by Google).

Now, I need some help.

#### Desired features:

1. data binding (one or two directional)
2. parsing custom elements, *ex:* `<my-element></my-element>` that output some predefined html
3. the custom elements should have the ability to wrap around nested elements, *ex:* `<my-element><h1>My title</h1></my-element>` that output the predifed html with the nested tag at the specified location inside that html (similar to webcomponents and Polymer)
4. minimum abstraction and no new syntax if possible (*except some mustache-like templating may be*)
5. a bonus would be html imports

#### Additionally:

1. should be stable
2. should be simple to use, simply drop in (not-in-the-way), not requiring some certain app structure
3. should do just template-engine things (*bad example:* Angular does abstract things too much, also include some jquery-like thing, etc)

#### My findings so far:

I found that **Polymer** is unstable with the shadow-dom and not working properly without it. **Reactjs** defines its own language which is unnecessary for me, **react** also requires nested components to be **react** components again, and don't allow to be html (limitation due to the custom language). **Skatejs** doesn't have data binding. **Rivet** has unstable custom elements and no ability to wrap nested elements. **Angular** directives are introducing the whole angular js abstraction, which is a bit too much only to get nice templating working.

#### My question

Is there alternative to the libraries I've tried that match the desired features listed above? If not, can you think of a way to mash some libraries together and achieve such functionality?

Comment: Sounds like you have been thorough!

Comment: Would you mind to explain what exactly in _Polymer_ you found unstable? It definitely suits your needs better than mentioned alternatives.

Comment: @mudasobwa things like https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/118 which is a deal breaker because you cant use third party plugins like dessandro's [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/). There's also a huge footprint of the polyfills on firefox for example. + (big plus) The entropy of Polymer is high as they say on their blog which is a big red flag.

Comment: I got your point. Whether you need the production-ready library yesterday, there are bad news. Web-components are still in draft stage. Polyfill penalties are unavoided at the moment. Unfortunately, there is no ready-to-use framework. You might want to take a look at [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) and/or [Mozilla Brick](https://mozbrick.github.io/index.html), but my advise would be to start with Polymer and hope that it will become stable ASAP.

Comment: This is one of the weird cases where up voting and voting to close both make sense on SO... the question is off topic though.

Comment: Brick shares the same polyfill library as Polymer. I'm currently reading: https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/component-based-angularjs-directives @FakeRainBrigand how is the question offtopic and how can I improve it?

Comment: @antitoxic, asking for off site resources (tutorials, libraries, etc.) is off topic.    The 'mash some libraries together' question could also be considered too broad, and while this is really a technicality, there's a 'one question per question' rule – though it's not really enforced.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand uh... Well it's going to be closed then. Is there a better place this can be moved to? I think it's an interesting topic and I've put a lot of time into it.

Comment: You could write it up in an email and CC the relevant mailing lists.

Comment: Hey, I'm the author of SkateJS and just wanted to jump in: SkateJS now has a functional rendering pipeline, so it's very much similar to using React, but for web components. No need for data binding etc. If you ever have any questions feel free to jump on skatejs/skatejs in Gitter.